# Adding 2d arrays to 1d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I add a 2d array into 1d array in java? Whenever I try to do that this message pops up:

```
Type Mismatch: cannot convert from char[][] to char
```

This is my code::

```
int numberOfCases = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

char[] grids = new char[numberOfCases];

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCases; i++) {
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        int gridDimensions = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        grids[i] = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions];

    }
}
```

Please help or give an alternative to what I am doing.

Comment: You are trying to add an two dimensional array to a char array. The char array can only contain chars. Otherwise you have to change that to `char[][][] grids`.

Comment: @Stephan can you tell me what's a 3d array?

Comment: If you already have 2d arrays and want to keep them in an array, it adds one dimension, so you need a 3d array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `grids` variable three-dimensional:

```
char[][][] grids = new char[numberOfCases][][];
```

Then, you should be able to add your two-dimensional array into this `grids` array.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui It works for me... all you need to do is modify the `char[] grids` line, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You actually instantiate a new char[][] and trying to make it equal to char[]

```
   grids[i] = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions];
```

That's what is going wrong.

Try to loop over all values in the multidimensional array, and adding them one per one to a 1d array :)

Comment: I then will have problems in the next step of my logic.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Which is? I don't know any other way to add them than to loop over all of them. If you really want to have a 1d array.

The three dimensional approach might work just as well though :)